# Cheap USB 3.0 hub

Tags: usb, hub

I'm looking for an external USB 3.0 hub for under $50 USD.

Requirements:

- USB 3.0
- At least 5 ports (More the better)
- Works on Windows 10
- External
- Looks nice mounted in one place (I won't be moving it, so it doesn't need to be portable or small)
- Able to transfer data to/from PC through multiple ports at once
- Able to transfer data between ports directly (Ex: from one external HDD to another)

It'd be nice to have an individual power switch for each port, but not required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend the [Anker 10-port USB hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NGQWL2).

It's a little bit on the expensive side, as it is normally listed for just under $80, but there is a sale on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NGQWL2) that has it listed for $33. Here are some of the features:

- Data Transfer to 5 Gb/s on all 7 available ports.
- 3 Additional "charging" ports that provide 2.1A so they can easily charge your phones, and your tablets.
- 4.4 stars from 1100 reviews, I've got to say that's pretty good :)

[image: The Ultimate USB Fashion Statement]

It looks fairly good as well, not ugly like a lot of other multi hubs. Hope that works out for you :)

Comment: Looks great ;).

Comment: I know! It's like *the* fashion statement for USB hubs :P

Comment: @Zizouz212 xD You should have added that to your answer. "It looks like a model for USB hubs, not ugly like the other ones."